# ruby on rails 4: could not find table 'table_name' even after a rake db:test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive the following error, even after doing a `rake db:test:prepare`. I am running rails 4.0.

```
1) Core::PostsController GET index assigns all posts as @posts
     Failure/Error: post = Post.create! valid_attributes
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'core_posts'
     # ./spec/controllers/core/posts_controller_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Core>'
```

I am running this test inside an engine, so could it be something related? My test looks like this:

```
module Core
  describe PostsController do

    # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
    # Post. As you add validations to Post, be sure to
    # adjust the attributes here as well.
    let(:valid_attributes) { {  } }

    # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
    # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
    # PostsController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
    let(:valid_session) { {} }

    describe "GET index" do
      it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
        post = Post.create! valid_attributes
        get :index, {}, valid_session
        assigns(:posts).should eq([post])
      end
    end


  end
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you actually create the table?

Comment: i presume rake db:test:prepare created it ...

Comment: Only if it exists in your development database and your schema file. Rails isn't psychic.

Comment: yeah, so I did rails db:migrate first, and then rails db:test:prepare. The schema does have:   create_table "core_posts", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

Comment: I just realised that my development.sqlite3 in my main app has data, but the development.sqlite3 inside my engine is empty. I am running rspec from inside my engine. I presume it is because of that?

Comment: Okay, so I couldn't migrate within the core engine since one of the migrations was conflicting with the main apps migration (I think). But either way. I am now facing another problem, but I think it's unrelated to this one, so if you want to wrap your comments in an answer, I would gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` into the engine dir & generate a dummy app for testing for your engine:

```
rails plugin new . --full --mountable --dummy-path spec/dummy
```

the above command will generate a full mountable engine with isolated namespace, meaning that all the controllers and models from this engine will be isolated within the namespace of the engine. For instance, the `Post` model later will be called `Core::Post`, and not simply `Post`. Since you have already generated the app -- incase of conflicts, you can skip the change.

Further, engine comes with a dummy application, located at `spec/dummy` because we told it to do that with the `--dummy_path` option. This dummy application is just a bare-bones Rails application that can be used to test the engine as if it was mounted inside a real application.

Then, you need to change rspec to use this dummy app, by making following changes:

inside `spec/spec_helper.rb` change this line

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

to this

```
require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment",__FILE__)
```

As `config/environment.rb` file doesn’t live two directories up, but rather inside `spec/dummy`.

Now, you can run the migration by following command.

```
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rake db:migrate
```

**Why not db:test:prepare?**

We cannot run rake db:test:prepare because it is unavailable. This
`db:migrate` task is especially altered for engines, and will run the migrations for the engine PLUS migrations within the `spec/dummy/db` folder.

Comment: `env RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`

Comment: after the migrations, where can I run test (bundle exec rspec spec) ? in the engine root directory or in dummy? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate your test DB

without rbenv

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare
```

with rbenv

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```